# Copying from arguments to array

Tags: assembly, x86, nasm

I'm trying to copy the 2nd argument to an array declared as:
`.bss X: resb 20`

I don't know how to approach this. Here's my attempt:

The argument ends in a terminating (0x0) character.

```
%include "asm_io.inc"
global asm_main

section .data

section .bss
  temp: resd 1
  i: resd 1
  X: resb 20

  length: resd 1 ; length of input

section .text

asm_main:
  enter 0, 0
  pusha

  mov ebx, dword [ebp+12]
  mov esi, dword [ebx+4]
loop: lodsb
  ; end of string?
  or al, al
  jz endloop

  ; copy arg[1] to x ================
  mov temp, X         ;error; temp = address of X 
  add temp, dword [i] ;error; temp += i
  mov byte [temp], al ;     ; temp[i] = al
  add dword [i], 1          ; i++
  ; =================================

  jmp loop
endloop:
  popa
  leave
  ret
```

I don't think I'm copying the array address correctly, it won't compile ^
The error is: "invalid combination of opcode and operands" for the two lines marked

Comment: `ebp` is not initialized at all. You need to set it up yourself if you intend to use it.

Comment: I didn't put all the code ^, I can if you need it. I've checked that it works, and have even printed the argument. Added SNIP lines.

Comment: See [MCVE]. Also, _won't compile_ is a bad problem description, you should at least provide error message and mark the relevant line. That said, `mov dword [temp], al` is definitely wrong since `al` is not a dword. Not sure what you wanted to do with the `temp` anyway.

Comment: Sorry, I just thought it was a simple thing that I was overlooking. Edited ^

Comment: x86 cannot take memory for both two operands. You have to use registers for at least one operand of `mov` and `add`.

Comment: MikeCAT, which register can I use? I don't really know how LODSB works, and I'm scared that I might mess with the array if I use one of the exx registers. Please advise.

Comment: Michael Petch, nope, no one named Sally :)

Comment: Probably used a fake name on Stackoverflow ;). The question being asked seems similar to some of hers http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34302055/loop-to-check-lowercase-letter-in-assembly

Comment: Yup, that's the same assignment alright.

Comment: If it's the same assignment, you don't really need to copy the argument, do you? XY problem ...

Comment: Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34058101/referencing-the-contents-of-a-memory-location-x86-addressing-modes.  It explains the difference between immediate operands (`value`) and memory operands (`[mem_location]`).

Comment: Same project.  Seems like lately a lot of people are asking about "maxLyn".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you can't address using a variable in memory, your `temp` is useless. You have to pick a register for it, say, `edi`. Then that block might look like:

```
  mov edi, X
  add edi, [i]
  mov [edi], al
```

This is of course overcomplicated, as is frequently the case with beginner code. A simpler version could look like:

```
  mov esi, [ebp+12]
  mov esi, [esi+4]
  mov edi, X
loop:
  lodsb
  stosb
  ; end of string?
  or al, al
  jnz loop
```

> I don't really know how LODSB works

You should then read the instruction set reference page about it. It uses `esi` and `al` but you already know that, why else would you load `esi` with the address and expect the result in `al` otherwise?